# prediction with R

Tags: r

I have 125 observations according to 14 modalities, and a 15th variable (output) and 25 other observations without the output (I have to predict it)
 I can not make histograms to visualize and have an idea of ​​correlation between each observation and the output
 I am stuck in the first lines
 I tried to install the Hmisc library but it's wrong every time

sous Rstudio

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster) 
library(Hmisc)
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/python/Desktop/Data.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE,strinsAsFactors = TRUE,encoding = "UTF-8") 
ind<-sample (2, nrow(data), replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))

dim(data)  #boite à moustache
install.packages(Hmisc)
install.packages
```

Comment: What is your problem? Are you having trouble installing the Hmisc package? To start, please show the exact error message as well as the code that causes it and a [mcve] of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first install the packages, before calling the libraries.

So :

```r
# The three first lines only need to be ran once and one at a time, as they install the packages on you environment
install.packages("Hmisc") 
install.packages("ggplot2") 
install.packages("cluster")

#Then, your code
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster) 
library(Hmisc)
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/python/Desktop/Data.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE,strinsAsFactors = TRUE,encoding = "UTF-8") 
ind<-sample (2, nrow(data), replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))

dim(data)  #boite à moustache
```

Hope this helps. If not, it would be interesting to share the error you get.

Comment: I'm sorry because i shared the publication with french , ididn't know it's only english     @seraphin i tried this also but i have error  Error in library(Hmisc) : aucun package nommé ‘Hmisc’ n'est trouvé

Comment: This message means that the package "Hmisc" doesn't seems to be installed properly. 
Can you try to run only this line :
install.packages("Hmisc")

And, then, the two others : 
`install.packages("ggplot2")` 
`install.packages("cluster")`

Before running the rest of the script? As I said earlier, the packages installation must only be done once.

Comment: Thank you so much, it doesnt work because i execute 3 packages at the same time when  tried to install one package only it worked

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped. 
(Could you edit your question with the error message and accept my response as the solution, so it can help other people with the same problem?)